# USB printer seemingly incompletely installed on WIndows 7

Tags: windows-7, usb, printing, printer

Running Windows 7 Home Premium, I plugged my HP DeskJet 812C printer into my HP desktop computer using an A–B cable, and Windows gave me the following error:

> [image: One of the USB devices attached to this computer has malfunctioned, and Windows does not recognize it.]

I then (nonetheless) tried using Windows's "Add Printer" facility. As a part of that process, Windows asked me what port to use; not seeing anything obviously USB‑y, I chose LPT1. Everything seemed to go okay (Windows claimed it was adding drivers), and the printer shows up on my list of printers, but nothing will print to it. Anything I try to print shows up in the printer's queue with status "Error - Printing". Moreover, if I right-click the printer's icon in Windows and select "Properties", I get this:

> [image: Device Information: Manufacturer: (Unavailable) Model: HP DeskJet 812C Model number: (Unavailable) Categories: Printer Description: (Unavailable) Device Functions: Name: (none) Type: (none)]

What can I do to get my printer to print?

Comment: Well 1) you need to get the USB to be recognized.  You may need a driver for your printer.  2) you set the printer to be on a parallel port. It will never find a USB printer.  You should have gotten a disk with the printer, there you should find drivers for it.

Comment: For most USB printers, you need to leave the printer disconnected until after the driver is loaded.  It will then instruct you when to connect the cable and it will recognize the printer.  Disconnect the USB cable, uninstall the driver, and start again.  You can also delete any printer that appears on LPT1 if you don't actually have a printer connected to the parallel port.

Answer (score 0):

try to install software designed for your printer manually, you can try by inserting a CD/DVD that came up with the printer or you can find one on-line from your printer company's website.